# How can I make tabs show in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I copy code from an editor into a Google Spreadsheets cell. Unfortunately, it left-aligns the code making it hard to read.

However, when I double-click on it to edit it, the tabs are still there (second image) so I know it didn't delete the tabs, just collapsed them.

**How do I get Google Spreadsheets to also display the code showing the tabs as tabs instead of collapsing them?**

[image: Indentation examples]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment, but a feature request has been made. See [this](http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=3d5bb7b737f6d75d&hl=en) link for more information.